# Add data to database from Controller, different methods but same row

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an entity model, for simplification purposes let's say it looks like this :

```
 public class Results {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
 private Long firstUser;
 private Long secondUser;
 private Double average;
 private Double median;
 private Double score;
 }
```

This is my ResultsService Implementation:

```
public class ResultsServiceImpl implements ResultsService{

@Autowired
private CalculateDataRepository calculateDataRepository;;

@Autowired
private ResultsService resultsService;

Results results=new Results();
public void Average(Long id1, Long id2){
    UserData firstClient = calculateDataRepository.findOne(id1);
    userData secondClient = calculateDataRepository.findOne(id2);
    clientId = firstClient.getClient().getId();
    secondId = secondClient.getClient().getId();
    Double average=(firstClient.getA()+secondClient.getA())/2;
    results.setAverage(average);
 }

 public void Score(Long id1, Long id2){
    SurveyData firstClient = surveyDataRepository.findOne(id1);
    SurveyData secondClient = surveyDataRepository.findOne(id2);
    clientId = firstClient.getClient().getId();
    secondId = secondClient.getClient().getId();
    Double average=(firstClient.getB()+secondClient.getB());
    results.setScore(average);
    results.setFirstUser(clientId );
    results.setSecondUser(secondId );
    resultsService.save(results);
 }

  ....
```

I tried declaring   Results results=new Results(); inside every method, but when I save them they get saved in different rows, instead of the same one.
How do I hold the reference so that when I call the setter of a field in one function, it's in the same row as the setter of a field in the other function.
To keep the problem focused, I tried to avoid showing the implementation of calculateDataRepository which is just the repository of an entity where some results are saved for different users.

The Results Method has no foreign field reference nor a reference from somewhere else, as there are fields firstUser and secondUser which I set from one of the methods;

Thank you.

Edit:

```
Results results=resultsService.findByFirstUserAndSecondUser(clientId, secondId);

if(results==null) {
        results= new Results();
        // Store to db ?

    }
    results.setAverage();
    resultsService.save(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need a method in ResultsRepository

```
Results findByFirstAndSecond(Long first, Long second);
```

In the each Average and Score methods (BTW Java naming convention requires to have method names start from lowercase letter) call the findByFirstAndSecond(id1, id2)

If the method returns null (no such result) create a new instance and save in the DB (INSERT). If some Results is returned store the info there and save changes in DB (UPDATE).

Comment: Thank you so much ! But how do I save the instance in the DB if I have no relationship of the Results table with any other table? So I can't use setResults().
I have updated the code to show you how I've added the findByFirstAndSecond and where I'm stuck if you can help

Comment: Both you methods must call `resultsService.save(results);` in the end saving either newly created or retrieved from DB instance

Comment: When I call .save from both methods, then on the database I have two rows, and each method saves the result in a separate row :|

Comment: No, It should not. If you save existing Results (with ID) retrieved from repository it should be updated (not inserted). If it is not check your repository code.

Comment: I'm sorry. Quick question if you have time;
When I return the method findBy-the ids, and save it in results of type Results. Then I check if(results==null){results=new Results(); -- how do I save this to the database? } so that outside the If, when I call setAverage for results, it saves for that row?

Comment: Finally you should have kind of ResultsRepository (the same level you have calculateDataRepository). In simple words if entity has key filed filled (the Id in your case) repository updates (using the filled id). If the id is not filled it inserts a new records and fills the id.